# Battery discharge rates and current limiting

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply

In a project I am building, I have a [CVCC](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5A-LED-Drive-Power-Supply-Module-Step-Down-CVCC-75W-Lithium-Battery-Charger-/400695001209?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5d4b488079) to control the current and keep it where I want it. (The circuit would definitely use more current it I didn't use the CVCC.) The problem arises because when I was looking over the battery I planned to use to power this, I realized that it would put out 13A for 0.1 hours if I let it. (If I read the specs right.) The issue is that the CVCC does not have a max input current on the spec sheet. While I believe that it would be able to limit the current down to what I want, I'd like to know if it would damage the CVCC to do that. (reduce the lifespan of the CVCC with continued use.)

Thanks!

**Edit:** I should also say that the battery has 1300MaH and a discharge rating of 10C.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you are misunderstanding how batteries and/or the CVCC work.

The specification of the battery just says 1300mAh, 10C to inform you that its energy content is approximately 1.3Ah, usually this is measured over multiple hours. For example 10 hours, so they then mean, if you take 130mA, the battery will supply this for a maximum of 10 hours.

When you take out higher currents than that it will effectively be only able to supply less. (for example if you take twice as much the total energy it can supply may be only 1200mAh).

The 10C means the absolute maximum current you are allowed to take is 10 times its capacity, i.e. the 13A you refer to. As stated, this will probably not last as much as 0.1hour, but high discharge LiPo packs are usually specified at a discharge of 1C during 1hour, so it may not be that much less.

What determines the rate at which your battery runs out is how much current your device sucks out of it.

The CVCC you link to is a switching DC/DC converter if I see right. This means that both the voltage and current at the input can be different from the output, as long as the power matches on both sides.

For example if you get 5V 1A out of it, that's 5W. If the efficiency of the device is then 80%, it means your input power is: Pin = 5 / 0.8 = 6.25W.
Now if your battery at a given moment is charged or discharged to 12.5V, that means the CVCC asks the battery for 6.25W/12.5V = 0.5A.

0.5A from the battery will work, because it is significantly less than the maximum current, and it will mean it can last approximately 1.3Ah/0.5A = 2.6 hours.

---

Edit: Of course the last estimate calculation is not accurate, as when the voltage of the battery drops the current will increase, to keep the constant output power available. Often when making such an estimation you either use the full battery characteristic curve for highest accuracy (a lot of work), or take the battery's median working voltage to calculate the average current and allow yourself 10% margin (easier, but with a risk of being a bit off)